# Return a substring using a regExp [Java]

Tags: java, android, regex, regexp-substr

I need to implement a function that, given as input a filename, returns a substring according to the specifications of a regular expression

Filenames are composed this way, I need to get the string in bold

> Doc20191001119049_**fotocontargasx**_3962122_943000.jpg
>
> Doc201810011052053_**fotoAssicurazioneCartaceo**_3962128_943000.jpg
>
> Doc201910011214020_**fotoesterna_ant**_396024_947112.jpg
>
> Doc201710071149010_**foto_TargaMid**_4007396_95010.jpg

I have currently implemented this:

```
Pattern rexExp = Pattern.compile("_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_");
```

But not work properly

Comment: Try `Pattern rexExp = Pattern.compile("_\\w+_(?=\\d{7}_)");`

Comment: Dont know if the different digit count are typos but this works `^Doc[\d+]{14,15}([^\d]+)[\d]{6,7}_[\d]{5,6}\.jpg$` for the all samples you've posted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1: Matching/extracting

You may capture `\w+` pattern inside `_`s that are followed with `[digits][_][digits][.][extension]`:

```
Pattern rexExp = Pattern.compile("_(\\w+)_\\d+_\\d+\\.[^.]*$");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VF2NLS/1)

**Details**

- `_` - an underscore
- `(\w+)` - 1+ letters/digits/`_`
- `_` - an underscore
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `_\d+` - `_` and 1+ digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^.]*` - 0+ chars other than `.`
- `$` - end of string.

[Online Java demo](http://ideone.com/L6WcK6):

```
String s = "Doc201810011052053_fotoAssicurazioneCartaceo_3962128_943000.jpg";
Pattern rexExp = Pattern.compile("_(\\w+)_\\d+_\\d+\\.[^.]*$");
Matcher matcher = rexExp.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
} // => fotoAssicurazioneCartaceo
```

## Solution 2: Trimming out unnecessary prefix/suffix

You may remove all from the start up to the first `_` including it, and `[digits][_][digits][.][extension]` at the end:

```
.replaceAll("^[^_]*_|_\\d+_\\d+\\.[^.]*$", "")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VF2NLS/2)

**Details**

- `^[^_]*_` - start of string, 0+ chars other than `_` and then `_`
- `|` - or
- `_\d+_\d+\.[^.]*$` - `_`, 1+ digits, `_`, 1+ digits, `.` and then 0+ chars other than `.` to the end  of the string.

Comment: You need to use `replaceAll`, not `replaceFirst`; otherwise, you'll get `fotoAssicurazioneCartaceo_3962128_943000.jpg` for `Doc201810011052053_fotoAssicurazioneCartaceo_3962128_943000.jpg` instead of `fotoAssicurazioneCartaceo`.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Wiktor's precise [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58325393/5699679), here's a "quick-and-dirty" way of doing it that makes the following hacky assumption about your input: "Required string is only non-numbers, surrounded by numbers, and the input is always a valid filepath".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] strs = {"Doc20191001119049_fotocontargasx_3962122_943000.jpg", "Doc201810011052053_fotoAssicurazioneCartaceo_3962128_943000.jpg", "Doc201910011214020_fotoesterna_ant_396024_947112.jpg", "Doc201710071149010_foto_TargaMid_4007396_95010.jpg"};
  var p = Pattern.compile("_([\\D_]+)_");
  for(var str : strs) {
    var m = p.matcher(str);
    if(m.find()) {
      System.out.println("found: "+m.group(1));
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
found: fotocontargasx
found: fotoAssicurazioneCartaceo
found: fotoesterna_ant
found: foto_TargaMid
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern: `(?<=_).+(?=(_\d+){2}\.)`

```
    final String s = "Doc20191001119049_fotocontargasx_3962122_943000.jpg\n"
        + "\n"
        + "Doc201810011052053_fotoAssicurazioneCartaceo_3962128_943000.jpg\n"
        + "\n"
        + "Doc201910011214020_fotoesterna_ant_396024_947112.jpg\n"
        + "\n"
        + "Doc201710071149010_foto_TargaMid_4007396_95010.jpg";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=_).+(?=(_\\d+){2}\\.)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        allMatches.add(matcher.group());
    }
```

Output: `[fotocontargasx, fotoAssicurazioneCartaceo, fotoesterna_ant, foto_TargaMid]`